# Visual Studio 2022 httpfile global variable for all files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, asp.net-web-api, webapi

We can create `.http` file in Visual Studio 2022 and call APIs. In each file we can defines a variable by using the syntax `@VariableName=Value` - for example:

```
@url = https://localhost:7000/api
```

Is it possible to declare @url **once** and use it in all `.http` files?

Answer (score 4):

We will create a file named httpenv.json. This file should be in the same folder as the HTTP file, or a folder above it. Visual Studio will look for that file in the folder where the HTTP file exists. If it’s not found, VS will look at through the parent directories to find it. When a file is found named httpenv.json, Visual Studio will stop searching for the file. The nearest file to the HTTP file found will be used. In this case I’ll add the httpenv.json to the same folder where the HTTP file is.

Note: Starting in 17.8 Preview 2, the names of the environment files will change to http-client.env.json and http-client.env.json.user. httpenv.json and httpenv.json.user will not be used after that.

```
{
  "dev": {
    "TemplatesApi_HostAddress": "localhost:44320",
    "searchTerm": "wpf"
  },
  "remote": {
    "TemplatesApi_HostAddress": "dotnetnew-api.azurewebsites.net",
    "searchTerm": "mads"
  }
}
```

[image]

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/safely-use-secrets-in-http-requests-in-visual-studio-2022/

My sample :
[image]

[image]

*** **important note** : If you have change any value in http-client.env.json, you must close the .http file and open it again because the values that are in http-client.env.json read when .http is open. (like changes in env path and terminal or powershell).
For example I save the jwt token in http-client.env.json file and after changing the token value I close User.http file and open it again.

http-client.env.json :

```
{
  "dev": {
    "url": "https://localhost:7000/api",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpIjoiNyIsInVpIjoiYzVjYmE0OTctMjEzOS00NjA5LTk5YzUtN2E4Zjc3Y2Q5OTEwIiwiciI6InUifQ.td1A8hLgz-JmTkFFyxDE8EEEpDIwgSFAWZRCcButRa4"
  }
}
```

User.http :

```
@controller = User
###
GET {{url}}/{{controller}}/GetAll
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful! You can mark it so that it can help more people

Comment: It looks like the filename is still httpenv.json in release build. Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.8.0

Comment: Both http-client.env.json and httpenv.json works.